# Knockout js : Read parent of parent's data

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, knockout

I want to read the parent of parent elements data. But, I can't able to read it properly.

My Array Screenshot :

[image]

My Code :

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: Object.keys($parent.optionParam()[main_id]), as: 'attribute' } -->
    <div class="product-custom-option-select">
        <p style="font-weight:bold;color:blue" data-bind="text:attribute"></p>
        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(Object.keys($parent.optionParam()[main_id][attribute])) -->
            <p style="font-weight:bold;color:green" data-bind="text:attribute"></p>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parents[1].optionParam[$parentContext.$index()][attribute] -->
                <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:sub_id"></p>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: !Array.isArray($parent.optionParam()[$index][attribute]) -->
            <p style="font-weight:bold;color:red" data-bind="text:attribute"></p>
            <p class="options-label" data-bind="text:attribute[$parents[1].main_id]"></p>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Using `$parent.optionParam()[main_id]` I can able to access 0 element array. So, in first `<p>` tag I get **Size** text as attribute.

Now, I want to read there are sub-element available in **Size or Color**, If true then, First Array.isArray() should be true and I can able to read   `sub_color` or `sub_id` field value.

```
<!-- ko if: Array.isArray(Object.keys($parent.optionParam()[main_id][attribute])) -->
```

This line always returns an error to me.

How can I read it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? Did it solve your query?

Answer (score 1):

`$parent` is essentially an array with all the parents in the current context.

So `$parent` or `$parent[0]` refers to immediate parent, `$parent[1]` will refer to grandparent or parent of parent and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to access parent's parent, try using `$parents[1]` instead of `$parent`. That worked for me